# Remove my own access rights from from files in a network folder from the commandline

Tags: command-line, permissions, ntfs

I have full access rights to a share on another Windows PC, e.g. \\Backup\PC. After I copied files from my normal Windows office PC to that share, I want to remove all rights from the copied files (e.g. \\Backup\PC\file.txt) so that I can only read and all other rights (write/modify/delete) are denied. The purpose of this is to make it harder for encryption trojans to encrypt the backup, should they ever make it onto the office PC. I know that I still have full access to the share and the trojans could set write-rights again, but I think/hope that they are not that smart. (Or is it possible to even remove these admin rights from the files? I must, however, be able to copy more files into the share in the future - and remove the write-rights from these files then, too.)

What are the exact commandline-commands (using icacls or similar) to set these rights (as executed on the office PC)?